# How to call another classes methods from another class?

Tags: ruby

I have the following structure

```
 class A
      def method1
      end
 end

 class B
       @my = A.new
       def classATest
          @myT.method1
       end

       def newTest
           classATest
       end
 end

 class C
      newB = B.new
      newB.newTest
 end
```

When I run class C, it gives me the error that it cannot find method1 of Class A (method newtest, calls method classATest, which calls the method1 using a global variable. What am I doing wrong? Is this not allowed?

Comment: One of Ruby's conventions is to use *snake-case* for names of methods and variables, meaning you might write `new_test` and `class_a_test` (or possibly `classA_test`). You don't have to do that, but 99%+ of us do. You may want to look at the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby/) when you have some time.

Answer (score 2):

Your line that says `@my = A.new` is not doing anything useful.  It's making a new object and assigning it as an instance variable of *class* B, but that kind of variable cannot be used by instances of B without extra effort.  You should replace that line with:

```
def initialize
  @myT = A.new
end
```

Also, you had a typo: you wrote `@my` in one place and `@myT` in another.

Alternatively, keep the code the way you have it and replace `@my` and `@myT` with the name of a constant, such as `MyA`.  Constants in Ruby start with capital letters, and can be used the way you are trying to use this variable.

Comment: The "extra effort" being `def newTest; self.class.instance_variable_get(:@my).send :method1;
 end`. The class instance variable `@a` and the instance variable `@a` are as different as night and day. It would be no different if they were named `@a` and `@b`. The return value is `nil` because `method1` returns nil. If you changed `method1` to `def method1; 'hi'; end`, `'hi'` would be returned.

Comment: ...but, but, but, I tested it.

Comment: Oops, I retract my earlier comment.  What I really mean is that the call to `send` is unnecessary, since `method1` is public.  At one point in time, you needed `send` because `instance_variable_get` was private.

Comment: Ah, `self.class.instance_variable_get(:@my).method1`. Thanks.